# How to activate band aggregation all thee time when available (4G+ at all times)?

Tags: networking, mobile-network, 4g

The 4g+ network only activates when network is under big load.
I'd like to have 4g+ activated as soon as it is available and as long as it is available.
Does anybody know where I can change the aggregation settings ?

Comment: Are you taking about multiple 4G links or the combination of 4G+5G? Which phone do you use?

Comment: I mean multiple 4g links, I'm using a one plus 7t pro it runs fine but only activates on network load